# Why does google chrome start automatically?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1

If I make a complete reboot and then check what is started before I run any browser, google chrome is running according to task mamanger. Why? When I start google chrome it starts multiple instances and if I shut it down the task manager displays that instances are still running. What can be done about it?

[image]

The bug seems spefici to my user account since from another user account (also administrator account) the behavarior of google chrome is not automatically starting.

Comment: Is it set in either MSCONFIG or Task Scheduler?

Comment: @TechLife, comments like this with citing a source are not helpful to any one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [AutoRuns for Windows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) :

This utility, which has the most comprehensive knowledge of auto-starting locations of any startup monitor, **shows you what programs are configured to run during system bootup or login**, and shows you the entries in the order Windows processes them. These programs include ones in your startup folder, Run, RunOnce, and other Registry keys. You can configure Autoruns to show other locations, including Explorer shell extensions, toolbars, browser helper objects, Winlogon notifications, auto-start services, and much more. Autoruns goes way beyond the MSConfig utility bundled with Windows Me and XP.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Some plugins such as Google Hangouts run inside a background instance of Chrome. What extensions do you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

I found out, under Windows 10, that I had the same problem. I actually tried a search in the Settings to find startup applications because I could not see any settings that would match such in the default.

The result was a process I could open. It is actually in the Task Manager. There is a new tab called "Startup" which lists the tasks that get started on a reboot. Right clicking on Chromium I could disable the awful feature.

So... Dead easy when you know where to look. I do not know whether that is different in Windows 8, but a search in your setting for "startup" should get you there.